# How to deserialize date (milliseconds) with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm working with a response like the following:

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P",
"issued_at":"1278448832702","instance_url":"https://na1.salesforce.com",
"signature":"0CmxinZir53Yex7nE0TD+zMpvIWYGb/bdJh6XfOH6EQ=","access_token":
"00Dx0000000BV7z!AR8AQAxo9UfVkh8AlV0Gomt9Czx9LjHnSSpwBMmbRcgKFmxOtvxjTrKW1
9ye6PE3Ds1eQz3z8jr3W7_VbWmEu4Q8TVGSTHxs"}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this into a class that looks like:

```
public class TokenResponse {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "issued_at")]
    public DateTime IssuedAt { get; set; }
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "instance_url")]
    public string InstanceUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

The call to deserialize is pretty simple:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(response.Content);
```

This results in an exception:

`Could not convert string to DateTime: 1278448832702.`

Is there a way I can get JSON.NET to deserialize this date correctly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a custom DateTime converter

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(response.Content, 
                                                      new MyDateTimeConverter());
```

---

```
public class MyDateTimeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var t = long.Parse((string)reader.Value);
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(t);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to override `CanWrite()` to return false.

Comment: To be accurate, you should use the constructor of `DateTime` that allows you to pass `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Comment: The `DateTime` needs to be constructed in UTC, like so: [`return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(t);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t882fzc6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's milliseconds per se, but instead the Unix epoch time, c.f. [this](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) article I found on developerforce.com

I believe that [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/1175/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-net-datetime) could help - it describes writing a custom JsonConverter which you can use with JSON.net to convert these epoch times to a DateTime.

Comment: I think the documentation may be wrong.  `1278448832702` seconds [works out to more than 40,000 years](https://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=9de714aba85e5449&q=1278448832702+seconds+%3D+%3F+years).  And in fact, if you try to do `new DateTime(1970,0,0).AddSeconds(1278448832702)` you will get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  More likely it *is* milliseconds.