# How to Convert Json to Object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, type-conversion

I want Convert Json to Object in C#. Json here is:

[{"value":"e920ce0f-e3f5-4c6f-8e3d-d2fbc51990e4"}].

How to do it using Object.

Question seems silly but it is not so stupid. 
I have not simple Json, I have IEnumerable and I am getting json from usint JsonResult like this:

new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims where (c.Type.Equals("value")) select new { c.Value });

This linq code does not work on JObject.

Thanks to Tommaso Belluzzo.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries out there to do that for you. A simple Google search will find many for you.

Comment: easy / simple answer to your question is a Simple Google search.. also read the `AskQuestion` link in the upper right hand side of this page ,navigate to `Question Help` and read the section on `How To Ask a Question`

Comment: Dato, take care with your questions. You can get a ban like me. Now i can to ask, but i'll make when i'm certain that the question is single and to make a good question. Take care. If you accept the response from **Tomazzo Belluzo** this help you to get reputation. Then, find out in the google or here before to ask.

Comment: I have found solution to converting in List:

List<string> l = (from c in User.Claims where (c.Type.Equals("value")) select new { c.Value }.ToString()).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NewtonSoft Json.NET library (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you can do as follows:

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

But your Json string looks more like an array, so probably `JArray.Parse` is what you need to use instead. Documentation with examples here:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm

If you want to parse the internal elements as objects, thhe accepted answer of this question should provide you enough hints:

[C# Parsing JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910476/c-sharp-parsing-json-array-of-objects)

Comment: Thank you Tommaso Belluzzo. Yes I understand question seems silly but it is not so stupid. I have not simple Json, I have IEnumerable<object> and I am getting json from usint JsonResult like this: 

new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims where (c.Type.Equals("value")) select new { c.Value }); 

This linq code does not work on JObject.

I am deleting question...
Thank you for answer again.

Comment: I doubt it can work with Linq. You have to format it. As I said, eventually, work with JArray.Parse.