# Implant Json Convertor for Entity Framwork db first Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, json.net

client send  object like this

```
{ID:1,JSONArray:[{Name:"pooria",LastName:"Shariatzadeh"},{Name:"jon",LastName:"smith"}]}
```

and My EF db First Class looks like This :

```
    public partial class entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string JSONArray { get; set; }
}
```

how can i implant something to Serializing and Deserializing automatically with Json.NET

i now how to Serializing and Deserializing json  i just want something like interface,Attribute or such thing for doing this in proper way

my solution is stringify JSONArray in client for setData and parse it when i get data but i want to do it in server side

Comment: You can have another parameter like `public object DeserializedJSON => Json.DeserializeObject<T>(JSONArray);`

Comment: @Phiter can you describe it more please

Comment: Presumably you have declared 2 properties `Name` and `Lastname` on the JSONArray object

Comment: @bilpor can you tell me how ?and noted  i have ef db first please

Comment: basically you should declare the properties on the class you have declared. Here's an example [using JsonArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910476/c-sharp-parsing-json-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i  have come with this solution

```
   public partial class entity
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string JSONArray { get; set; }
      public List<JSONArray> JSONArrayList
    {
        get { 
        if (Tags != null)  
           return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONArray>>(JSONArray); 
        else 
            return null; 
    }
        set 
         { 
           if (value != null) 
           JSONArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
         }
    } 
  }


  public class JSONArray
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

If you have it in another Way please share