# asp.net put an empty C# list to razor view and fill it up inside

Tags: asp.net, razor

I want to put an empty C# List to the razor view. Inside of the view I get array of data (taken from JavaScript code). Fill the content of the array into the C# List and put it back to the controller.

**Now, I know that is not possible**, then I find a more simpler solution, see details in my example.

One Item of the collection

```
public class GrafikSpielItem
{
    public String Stil { get; set; }
    public int XStart { get; set; }
    public int YStart { get; set; }
    public int XStop { get; set; }
    public int YStop { get; set; }        
    public String Farbe { get; set; }
}
```

controller class

```
 // GET: GrafikSpiel
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AufgabeB(string[] arr)
{
    // arr is the JSON-String from Grafik.js

    if (arr == null) return View();

    List<GrafikSpielItem> items = new List<GrafikSpielItem>();

    // adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910476/c-sharp-parsing-json-array-of-objects
    // Thanks to: Bibaswann Bandyopadhyay
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(arr[0]);
    foreach (JObject obj in array.Children<JObject>())
    {
        var item = new GrafikSpielItem();
        int nCounter = 1;
        foreach (JProperty singleProp in obj.Properties())
        {
            switch(nCounter)
            {
                case 1: item.Stil = singleProp.Value.ToString(); break;
                // case 2: ..

                default:
                    break;
            }
            nCounter++;
        }
        items.Add(item);
    }     


    // not implemented yet
    // connect to database
    // db.SetData(items)


    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Razor view

```
...
   // moved source code from here to JS

    <script src="~/Scripts/Grafik.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript: Grafik.js

```
// convert simple array to JSON and send it back to controller
 var arrStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(linesArray));
 var url = "AufgabeB?arr=" + arrStr;
 window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: Your code seems a bit mixed up in the Razor view. Maybe you should find some tutorial? The code in the `<script>` tag in the view seems to be a mix of javascript and C#, which is not possible. All operations with the C# model are only valid server side, when the server processes the view, before it is returned to the client. If you write in javascript you are on the client side, and have no access to the C# model that made up the page. You need to post back the javascript objects to the `AufgabeB(...)` method. This might be done either using the form or  using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - see edited code - thanks to user mortb and user Bibaswann Bandyopadhyay.