# Is there a way to write custom JsonConverter per object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json object something like this:

```
{"company": "My Company",
"companyStart" : "2015/01/01",
"employee" : 
    { "name" : "john doe",
      "startDate" : 1420434000000 } }
```

And my json object like this:

```
public class Company {
    public string company;
    public DateTime companyStart;
    public Employee employee;
}

public class Employee {
    public string name;
    public DateTime startDate;
 }
```

My original code deserialize like this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(jsonString);
```

This code converts Company.companyStart without trouble, but when it gets to Employee.startDate it doesn't know what to do with the Long.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088406/how-to-deserialize-date-milliseconds-with-json-net) post showed me how to create custom JsonConverter to convert long to DateTime, but as you can see in my case, this would give me trouble converting Company.companyStart to DateTime.

So...  I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
public class Company : JsonBase {
    ...
}

public class Employee : JsonBase {
    ...
    Employee() { Converter = new CustomDateConverter(); }
}

public class JsonBase {
    private JsonConverter converter;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public JsonConverter Converter => converter ?? (converter = new StandardConverter());
}
```

JsonBase would contain either the standard converter or

and in my code I would convert something like this:

```
public T CreateJsonObject<T>() where T : JsonBase {
    JsonBase json = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T));
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString, json.Converter);
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't quite work because this method will simply use the top most Converter to convert everything instead of using converter per object.

Is there a way to use the converter per object?  Or perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Ooops.  I missed some words in my post: "JsonBase would contain either the standard converter or custom converter"

Comment: go here -http://json2csharp.com/ and paste your json it will generate a C# Class for you.

Comment: cool tool.  but I need to have the "startDate" as DateTime, not as long.

Comment: If you use Newtonsoft's JSON.NET you can control the serialization and deserialization of objects by customization: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/. You can also use the built in attribute converters/properties or write your own: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about adapting the custom converter that you wrote to understand both formats:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.ValueType == typeof(string))
    {
        return DateTime.Parse((string)reader.Value);
    }
    else if (reader.ValueType == typeof(long))
    {
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds((long)reader.Value);
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Alternatively you could apply the converter only to a specific property of your model by decorating it with the `JsonConverter` attribute:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string name;

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
    public DateTime startDate;
}
```

This way you don't need to register the converter globally and it won't mess up with the other standard date formats.

Comment: As always, I was over engineering my solution.  Your JsonConverter attribute is so simple.  Thanks!